# How to check if HTML file has correct syntax?

Tags: html, c, syntax, tags

I'm quite new to C, though I've learned C and C# and some other minor languages. My question is: how can I check if a HTML file has correct syntax? I mean:

```
<html><head></head><body>random stuff
```

and

```
<tag></tag>random stuff</body></html>
```

I thought of making a stack but I'm lost. It sounds too complicated to read from file char by char and put in so many `if`s.

Does anyone have an idea how I can write this? As I said I'm new to C so it would be immensely appreciated if you could attach some code to your explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a simple Lexer and Parser for HTML.

Check out Lex(or Flex) and Yacc(Or Bison) and how to use them.

See this for a simple Yacc Grammar for an older version of HTML [Simple Yacc Grammar for HTML](http://1997.webhistory.org/www.lists/www-html.1995q1/0019.html)

Here is another SIMPLE XML Parser: [XML Grammar](http://www.w3.org/XML/9707/parser.y) and [XML Lexer](http://www.w3.org/XML/9707/scanner.l)

My advice: don't write everything from scratch. Use pre-existing tools to help you do what you want. using Lex and Yacc will be less error prone, than a hand written lexer/parser

Comment: thank you but i'm quite sure there is an easy way to approach this problem. it's similar to a correct parenthesis problem, which could be written with a stack and a few simple functions, i was only interested if anyone could do better than that. but thanks anyway

Comment: @GáborBirkás: there's may be a simple solution if you simplify the problem. "Correct syntax for HTML" has a complex definition. It includes processing instructions, tags with optional close-tags, different allowed attributes on each element, and other miscellaneous stuff that breaks everyone's first attempt to parse it.

Comment: @GáborBirkás first step to being a good programmer is to use tools that help you in solving a real world problem. parsing an HTML data is a real world problem, solving it requires real world solutions and real world tools

Comment: Just an example, the following is incorrect HTML, because the open-pre and open-body are part of the comment `<!-- here's a comment-- --> <body><pre>--></pre></body>`. Most browsers close the comment at the first --> and display `-->`. So as well as deciding whether to check the syntax "properly" you need to decide whether to be more proper than a typical browser.

Comment: Another example for flaw in stack based approach is: the many levels of recursive depth. How will you solve if your HTML was like this: 
`<html><body><ul><li><p><a></a></p><p></p><p></p><img src=""/></li></ul></body></html>`

Comment: @PrototypeStark: a stack solves that example, I think. Push each open-tag onto the stack (except for the `img` which is self-closing). As you encounter each close, pop the stack and check whether the element name is the same. The same stack rejects `<body><p><p></p></body>`, which is OK HTML but not XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you asking this? Do you want a challenge or do you simply want to check if your html is validated? If the latter is the case you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3cmarkupvalida/.

It is written in C# and uses the API of the W3 HTML Validator application (http://validator.w3.org/) to validate an HTML document and receive as response if it is valid or not as well as errors and warnings.

You could also directly use http://validator.w3.org/ of course...

Answer (score 1):

I think using a stack is a good idea. You can follow the below approach 
1. Read a line in a buffer. (Assuming that your HTML file is properly formatted) 
2. STOP at  '<' character in the line.
3. Read the characters in another buffer until '>' is encountered. 
4. Does the tag contain '/'. If no, Goto 5 else goto 6.
5. Push this tag into stack. 
6. Pop a tag from the stack and compare it with the tag just read.. 
7. GOTO 1 until the file is read completely

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? be productive use a tool to help you.

Comment: Why not? The person is new to C and wants to create a basic parser. It t would be a good exercise.

Comment: Then he can write a recursive descent parser and a hand written lexer to help him. But there is no point. Oh and btw, having a stack will only solve half the problem. Imagine you will have to take care of the attributes and see if they're valid for each tag. ETC ETC. There's a lot of processing that's needed. Its not trivial and definitely not for "beginners" in C. Hence a lexer/parser.

Comment: oh and by the way i don't want to make like a html validator, it's a correct parenthesis problem or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS/HTML validators

- CSS Validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
- HTML Validator: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri…